# Display data with ViewBag and DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display data with a ViewBag but I don't know how to use the id of a DropDownListFor, here is my code

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var liprojs = (from p in db.Projets
                       join uip in db.UtilisateurInProjets on p.ProjetId equals uip.ProjetId
                       where uip.UtilisateurId == 156
                       select new { p.Libelle }).ToList();
        ViewBag.liprojs2 = liprojs.First().Libelle;
        return View();
    }
```

View :

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.liprojs2)
                {
                    @item
                }
```

And I get the name of the item with the id 156 but i would like to display the item thanks to the selected value of a DropDownListFor.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your database structure is so I tried making a mockup which you 
can try to use.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<SelectListItem> liprojsList = (from p in db.Projets
                   join uip in db.UtilisateurInProjets on p.ProjetId equals uip.ProjetId
                   where uip.UtilisateurId == 156
                   select new SelectListItem { Value = p.Libelle.Id.ToString(), Text = p.Libelle.Name }).ToList();

    ViewBag.liprojs = liprojsList;

    return View();
}
```

Then in your view use something like this?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PropertyToStoreValue, ViewBag.liprojs)
```

Comment: not exactly, i would like to change the 156 into a variable ID and ID comes from another dropdowlist so i can diplay a dynamic viewbag